# python join/format possible hex values for regex

Tags: python, string, hex

I'd like to create a template string as possible values for an expression:

```
'\x1C,\x2C,\x3C,\x4C,\x5C,\x6C,\x7C,\x8C,\x9C,\xAC,\xBC,\xCC,\xDC,\xEC,\xFC'
```

in a manner like this:

```
from string import digits, ascii_uppercase
','.join(['\x'+i+'C' for i in digits+ascii_uppercase[:6]])
```

but unfortunately join does not treat '\x' litterally:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape
```

Unlike, for example, double slashes:

```
','.join(['\\x'+i+'C' for i in digits+ascii_uppercase[:6]])
\\x0C,\\x1C,\\x2C,\\x3C,\\x4C,\\x5C,\\x6C,\\x7C,\\x8C,\\x9C,\\xAC,\\xBC,\\xCC,\\xDC,\\xEC,\\xFC'
```

Any ideas around this? Maybe another encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with characters, deal with characters.

```
','.join(chr(x) for x in range(0x1c, 0x100, 0x10))
```

Answer (score 0):

`\x` will try to escape `\x` like `\n` (newline), you need use `\\` to use the first `\` escape the second `\`.

However, the two `\` only display when you just type it in shell, but when you *print it out* the another one will be gone:

```
>>> text = '\\x0C,\\x1C,\\x2C,\\x3C,\\x4C,\\x5C,\\x6C,\\x7C,\\x8C,\\x9C,\\xAC,\\    xBC,\\xCC,\\xDC,\\xEC,\\xFC'
>>> text
'\\x0C,\\x1C,\\x2C,\\x3C,\\x4C,\\x5C,\\x6C,\\x7C,\\x8C,\\x9C,\\xAC,\\xBC,\\xCC,\\xDC,\\xEC,\\xFC'
>>> print(text)
\x0C,\x1C,\x2C,\x3C,\x4C,\x5C,\x6C,\x7C,\x8C,\x9C,\xAC,\xBC,\xCC,\xDC,\xEC,\xFC
```